# C How can I write a value to an entire data structure, rather than just an element?

Tags: type-conversion, structure, 9-bit-serial

I am attempting to write a little C test program for reading data from a vending machine.  I have the circuit hooked up, now the hard part is the code.
The machine uses UART that calls for 9 total data bits.  Here is my code.  Attempting to write directly to the full 9 bit data type does not work, but writing to an element of it does.

```
struct nineBit {        //To make 9 bit character types for an array.
unsigned int data : 8;  //8 data bits.
unsigned int mode : 1;  //1 'mode' bit.
} data[35];             //Make an array of 9 bit data to store the incoming data block.

void setup() {
Serial1.begin(9600, SERIAL_9N1);  //Start the UART.
}

void loop() {
data[0] = Serial1.read();  //Works if 'data[0].data is entered instead.
                           //How can I transfer this all in one command?
}
```

Errors are
    rx.cpp: In function 'void loop()':
    rx.cpp:11:12: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'nineBit' and 'int')
    void setup() {
            ^

```
rx.cpp:11:12: note: candidates are:
rx.cpp:1:8: note: nineBit& nineBit::operator=(const nineBit&)

    ^
rx.cpp:1:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int' to 'const nineBit&'
rx.cpp:1:8: note: nineBit& nineBit::operator=(nineBit&&)
rx.cpp:1:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int' to 'nineBit&&'
make[1]: *** [../build/target/user/platform-6rx.o] Error 1
make: *** [user] Error 2
Error: Could not compile. Please review your code.
```

Comment: Have you tried `data[0] = (struct nineBit *)Serial1.read();` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using arduino or something similar. So `Serial1.read()` returns `char`. `char` is a signed 1 byte (8 bits) field. And your `struct nineBit` has 9 bits. How do you expect of writing 8 bits to 9 bited structure?

A note about your structure: it doesn't have size equal 9 bits. Instance of any variable can have size evaluated in bytes only. So if you want to store 9 bits you have to create a two byted structure or more.

And in fact `sizeof(nineBit)` equals 4 because your bit field have `unsigned int` type. If you want to reduce size of your structure you have to change bit field type to either `short` or `char`.

Let's assume your serial transports two bytes per every structure. So you have to read two bytes and then assign them:

```
struct nineBit {        
    char data : 8;  //8 data bits.
    char mode : 1;  //1 'mode' bit.
} data[35];             

void setup() {
    Serial1.begin(9600, SERIAL_9N1);  //Start the UART.
}

void loop() {
    char byte1=Serial1.read();
    char byte2=Serial1.read();
    data[0].data=byte1;
    data[0].mode=byte2;
}
```

If you want to use only a single line you have to write a C function or overload `operator=` if you use C++.

**C way**

```
struct nineBit {        
    char data : 8;  //8 data bits.
    char mode : 1;  //1 'mode' bit.
} data[35];    

void writeToNineBit(struct nineBit *value){
    char byte1=Serial1.read();
    char byte2=Serial1.read();
    value->data=byte1;
    value->mode=byte2;
}

void setup() {
    Serial1.begin(9600, SERIAL_9N1);  //Start the UART.
}

void loop() {
    writeToNineBit(data+0);   // or &data[0]..  0 is an index in array..
}
```

**C++ way**

```
struct nineBit {        
    char data : 8;  //8 data bits.
    char mode : 1;  //1 'mode' bit.

    //    assume you have to assign data without mode..
    nineBit& operator=(char b){
        this->data=b;
    }
} data[35];    

void setup() {
    Serial1.begin(9600, SERIAL_9N1);  //Start the UART.
}

void loop() {
    data[0]=Serial1.read();    //  now it works cause you have operator overloading in your structure..
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, although your code does not compile either.  It says

Comment: 'writeToNinebit was declared void', 'nineBit was not declared in this scope', and 'value was not declared in this scope'.   I am using a 'Particle photon' board, last time I used an arduino.  I just accessed registers directly, I had to extract the ninth bit from a UART status register, and then copy the data bits from the receiving register.  I am unsure if this device does it the same way, but feel like that may help.

Comment: It appears you just forgot to add 'struct' in the parenthases of your writeToNineBit method.  Thanks, I'll work on trying to understand all the parts that are new to me.